# Date and Time string manipulation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a Date Time string `2018-08-10T14:33:44.000Z` . I want to convert it into, `2018-08-10 14:33:44` by using Javascript.

I can convert it to UTC or Local time. But, I am looking for that specific format only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, since your input is a datetime *string*, you can transform the string easily with a regular expression, no need to mess with date manipulation at all. Match the `T`, capture the following time string in a group, then replace the T and everything that follows with a space followed by that group:

```js
const input = '2018-08-10T14:33:44.000Z'
console.log(
  input.replace(/T((\d{2}:){2}\d\d).+/, ' $1')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'moment' javascript library. Then you can do something like:

```
moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```